# In Vuejs, remove the object values in URL after passing object in router query?

Tags: vue.js

```
<button class="viewButton body" @click="this.$router.push({ name: 'Staff Profile', query:{obj: JSON.stringify(sdList[s.staff_id-1])} })">More Details ></button>
```

[image: How do I remove the object values in url? - Please click in this link to view image.]

Desire output: To remove the information after obj (refer to the image above) --> /staffProfile?obj

This is what I have tried to do in order to remove but cannot get it working:

```
<button class="viewButton body" @click="this.$router.push({ name: 'Staff Profile', query:{obj: JSON.stringify(sdList[s.staff_id-1]), as: "/staffDetails"} })">More Details ></button>
```

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim Thanks for editing. Due to my reputation, I am not able to add image yet. It only allow me to add image link.

Comment: You're welcome, please clarify more your question

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Done! By any chance, do you know how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [history.replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) to change the URL without navigating.  Place this in the created hook of the page you're loading:

```js
created() {
    history.replaceState(history.state, "", "/staffProfile");
}
```

downsides include losing the query params if you manually reload the page or while manually navigating back to the previous page then forward.  Only when clicking your button will the page load with the query params intact.  If you need an alternative solution that always preserves this data, you might want to look into saving the query params using a state management library (Vuex or Pinia), or the browser's localStorage API